# Messnger shared content

Tags: facebook-messenger

I'd like to remove the pictures that are in messenger's shared content. Both of us have tried deleting the conversations and the shared content still shows up after we send a message to eachother.  We have also both tried blocking eachother, uninstalling messenger & Facebook from our cell phones. Please help thank you.

Comment: Have you tried deleting those particular images/messages (not the whole conversation) from your chat by `Pressing and holding the message > Delete`